# Is there a way to add AMP list in AMP forms in "submit-success"?

Tags: forms, amp-html

I want to add listings on AMP form submit but I am not sure if there is a way to do it.

Need help in this.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can render dynamic HTML in your form response:

```
<form method="post"
  action-xhr="/submit"
  target="_top">
  ...
  <div submit-success>
    <template type="amp-mustache">
      Hello {{name}}!
    </template>
  </div>
</form>
```

See the live example [here](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/#form-submission-with-page-update).